# How to redirect to edit page on node create?

Tags: 8, redirection

I am trying this code in my custom module but it does not redirect to the node edit page.

```
 function mymodule_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
   if ($entity instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface){
        $id=$entity->id();
        return new RedirectResponse("/node/$id/edit");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just add a new submit handler via form alter, and in that callback do the redirect rather than hook_entity_insert? Then you can just use $form_state->setRedirect. See this question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/202284/57  Just make sure your handler is at the end of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When not in a Controller call the `send()` method on the `RedirectResponse` object.

```
$response = new RedirectResponse("/node/$id/edit");
$response->send();
```

Comment: Maybe, but it's wrong. this should be done through a form alter and $form_state  as suggested in the comment from @Kevin. Sending responses yourself is almost always a bad idea, maybe you'll create nodes through API calls, imports or something else and that's going to kill that

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem very similar and this is how I solved the situation:

```
 use Drupal\Core\Url;

 function mymodule_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
   if ($entity instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface){
        $id = $entity->id();
        // You should use the route instead of path.
        $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => $id])->toString();
        // Redirecting to edit.
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        $response->send();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I tried this, but at this stage, just prior to insert, the entity doesn't yet have an id; it's null.