# Redirect to view display after form submission

Tags: views, forms, redirection

I'm using a `form_alter` hook to add a custom submit callback. I want to redirect the user to a particular page display of a view. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to specify the path.

In my custom submit hook, I tried `$form_state->setRedirect('/my-view/page/path');` but that didn't work. From searching, I found this question, [Redirect after form submission](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202284/redirect-after-form-submission), but the answers indicate to specify the machine name of a path from a routing yaml file.

I'm wanting to redirect the user to a views page display that I built in the UI, so I don't have any routing.yml file (that I'm aware of) where I could glean a machine name of a path from.

How do I set the redirect in a custom submit handler to a page display of a view?

Answer (score 1):

Routes are not only defined in yaml files, but also dynamically in route subscribers.

[`Drupal\views\EventSubscriber\RouteSubscriber`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21EventSubscriber%21RouteSubscriber.php/class/RouteSubscriber/8.7.x) collects routes from all views displays which implement [`DisplayRouterInterface::collectRoutes`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21display%21DisplayRouterInterface.php/function/DisplayRouterInterface%3A%3AcollectRoutes/8.7.x), like the *Page* display:

*[PathPluginBase::collectRoutes](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21display%21PathPluginBase.php/function/PathPluginBase%3A%3AcollectRoutes/8.7.x):*

```
  public function collectRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    $view_id = $this->view->storage->id();
    $display_id = $this->display['id'];

    $route = $this->getRoute($view_id, $display_id);

    if (!($route_name = $this->getOption('route_name'))) {
      $route_name = "view.$view_id.$display_id";
    }
    $collection->add($route_name, $route);
    return ["$view_id.$display_id" => $route_name];
  }
```

This produces route names like `view.my_view.page_1` and you can redirect in a form submit:

```
$form_state->setRedirect('view.my_view.page_1');
```